# graphviz segmentation fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, graphviz

I'm building a graph with many nodes, around 3000. I wrote a simple python program to do the trick with graphviz, but it gives me segmentation fault and I don't know why, if the graph is too big or if i'm missing something.

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Import graphviz
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/graphviz')
import gv

# Import pygraph
from pygraph.classes.graph import graph
from pygraph.classes.digraph import digraph
from pygraph.algorithms.searching import breadth_first_search
from pygraph.readwrite.dot import write

# Graph creation
gr = graph()

file = open('nodes.dat', 'r')
line = file.readline()
while line:
        gr.add_nodes([line[0:-1]])
        line = file.readline()

file.close()
print 'nodes finished, beginning edges'

edges = open('edges_ok.dat', 'r')
edge = edges.readline()
while edge:
        gr.add_edge((edge.split()[0], edge.split()[1]))
        edge = edges.readline()

edges.close()
print 'edges finished'
print 'Drawing'

# Draw as PNG
dot = write(gr)
gvv = gv.readstring(dot)
gv.layout(gvv,'dot')
gv.render(gvv,'svg','graph.svg')
```

and it crashes at the `gv.layout()` call.

The files are somthing like:
nodes:

```
   node1
   node2
   node3
```

edges_ok:

```
   node1 node2
   node2 node3
```

Comment: Sounds like you should report that to the Graphviz maintainers?

Comment: I surely do that if it's not a programmer related problem.

Comment: Have you tried building a dot file and processing it with (command-line) dotty? Does that also segphault?

Comment: I'll try this and let you know if it worked, even if it's not a real solution.

Comment: @LucaB: even if it doesn't solve your problem it's a good way to find out where exactly the problem lies. If that also segfaults, then you can be pretty sure taht it's not an error in how you call it (or in the Python bindings)

Comment: If Graphviz is segfaulting, that's a bug in Graphviz.  The software is mature enough that it should *gracefully* handle *any* errors.

Comment: I reported this to graphviz bug tracking system.

Comment: Anyway, changing the layout from dot to neato solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed the layout type from dot to neato and that solved the problem.

I searched a bit and it seems that the dot layout is a bit faulty on large graphs.

Comment: "`I  changed the layout type from dot to neato `" ... Can you tell us how you did this?

Comment: Nvm, just change `dot` to `neato`.  E.g `dot -Tsvg x.gv -o x.svg` becomes `neato-Tsvg x.gv -o x.svg`

Comment: Note from the future: Nope, changing to neato may have worked 12 years ago but it doesn't consistently solve the problem anymore. My graph isn't even that large and neither works.